# Delay in getting messages from AWS SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, queue, amazon-ecs, amazon-sqs

I am adding messages in SQS on Lambda and then receiving the messages inside a container on ECS.
The problem is there is a 10-15 seconds of delay when I am receiving the messages on the container.

On the container a loop is running indefinitely every 1 second where I am getting messages and if available processing it.

Example:
Suppose the message is added in SQS at 15:20:00 but I am able to get that message at 15:20:15 on ECS. These 15 seconds are too long for my use case.

Can this time be reduced ?
Assuming that there are multiple producers and consumers is there any alternative solution ?

Comment: Are there other messages in the queue, or is that the only message? If there are other messages, the worker(s) in the container(s) might be busy and not asking for all of the messages.

Comment: No there is only 1 message in the SQS. I tried this with multiple messages and also with only 1 message, the behaviour is same.

Comment: Messages in Amazon SQS are available as soon as they are sent. Either your workers are not correctly retrieving messages or, perhaps it is a FIFO queue and another message with the same MessageGroupId is being processed.

Comment: I am using a Standard queue. Can you tell the correct way to retrieve messages for this problem ?

Comment: The _only_ way to receive messages is to call `ReceiveMessage()`. I would suggest that you do some logging to see precisely when and how often the worker is calling `ReceiveMessage()`. An efficient method is to specify `WaitTimeSeconds=20` as a parameter, which will cause the request to 'wait' up to 20 seconds before returning an empty result. This reduces the need to continually poll the queue.

Comment: Okay, it'll specify WaitTimeSeconds and check. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, using WaitTimeSeconds=20 worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

If your workers are continually polling the Amazon SQS queue, they can reduce the amount of requests by specifying `WaitTimeSeconds=20` (which is its maximum value).

This tells Amazon SQS to wait until at least one message is available, to a maximum of 20 seconds. If no messages are available after 20 seconds, an empty set of messages is returned. However, if one or more messages appear in the queue, then the call *returns immediately* without waiting for 20 seconds.

This reduces the frequency of calls to SQS and might increase stability in your application.